# trying to slide a p tag class to the right

Tags: jquery, anchor, slide

I have the following code that isnt working for me, I am trying to slide a p tag to the left with a animation on a click function

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.portfolio').click(function(){

     $('#rightcontent1').animate({width: '783px', height: '579px'}, 200);
     $('.homeText').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Are you getting an error? Can you post a complete example?

Comment: also, it should be noted that the slide direction in title of your question, the body of your question, and your code are all different.

Comment: @j08691 the class just doesnt hide at all, howerver it does work if i just do $('.homtText').hide();

Answer (score 1):

hide() syntax is different but that on animate()

Your function:

```
     $('.homeText').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
```

Doesn't work as your hide() syntax is incorrect. function should be rewritten:

```
     $('.homeText').slideUp(1000);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/hide/ for more info about hide syntax.